# Double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

Calculate the iterated integral $$\int_{1} ^4\int_{1} ^2 \left(\frac xy+\frac yx\right)\,dy\,dx$$
This is the work that I've done, but it'd lead me to the wrong answer, so either I did it completely wrong or I made in error in my calculation.
$$\int_{1} ^4\int_{1} ^2 \left(\frac xy+\frac yx\right)\,dy\,dx= \int_{1} ^4 \left[xln(y)+{y^2\over 2x}  \right]_{1} ^2 dx=\int_{1} ^4 \left[xln(2)+ {3\over 2x}\right]dx= \left[{ln(2)x^2\over 2}+\frac32ln(x)\right]_{1} ^4= {15\over 2}ln(2)+ {3\over 2}ln(4)$$    The answer in the back of the book says it's ${21\over 2}ln(2)$

Comment: what book is it? Just curious

Comment: Calculus Concepts and Contexts by James Stewart. The question is in chapter 12 section 2, page 843 number 9.

Comment: I'm not one that really cares much for any kind of textbook that has to deal with any type of science or math, but I actually find this book to be pretty helpful for the most part. There are some sections in the book that I don't feel like it does a good job explaining, but overall, I find it very useful. Are you a calculus professor?

Comment: I'm a simple student and am looking for this kind of exercieses that's why i asked (:

Comment: My professor makes up his own extra problems that are assigned on top of the book problems. They are pretty challenging, but very helpful when it comes to better understanding the concepts. Would you like me to show you some of them?

Comment: Sure.I'm looking for problems on multivariable calculus especially integration ( Stokes,Green,Gauss-Theroem).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9736/discussion-between-jc-e-and-amire-bendjeddou)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answer is correct: note that $\ln(4)=\ln(2^2)=2\ln(2)$, so your solution becomes ${15\over 2}\ln(2)+ {3\over 2}\ln(4)={15\over 2}\ln(2)+ 3\ln(2)={21\over 2}\ln(2)$.

Comment: Hahaha! Of course I would forget about that! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that  $$\ln(4)=2 \ln(2)$$

Comment: Oh yeah! I totally forgot :P Thanks!